# How can I run a AWS Cron Job which will run for the whole week with an exception (I should not run on sat 9 AM to sun 9AM)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cron

How to run a Cron job every 15 minutes , but it should NOT run between 9:00 (AM) to to 9:00 (AM) on weekends.

Comment: Schedule the cron job to run every 15 minutes and then in the lambda return if the current invocation is within the blocked time slot.

Comment: Can you clarify: `but it should NOT run between 9:00 (AM) to to 9:00 (AM) on weekends.`.

Comment: @jens It should not invoke lambda between SAT 9 AM to SUN 9 AM

Answer (score 2):

You can use a scheduled [EventBridge](https://aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/) event.

I don't fully understand your requirement regarding weekends, but I think you can not solve it with a single rule.

So what I would recommend is to have two scheduled EventBridge events. One for the week and one for the weekend. Both will trigger the same Lambda.

Weekday pattern:

```
0/15 * ? * MON-FRI *
```

Weekend pattern from 12am (midnight) to 9am:

```
0/15 0-9 ? * SAT-SUN *
```

Check out the documentation on how to create such a event and trigger your Lambda:

1. [Creating an Amazon EventBridge rule that runs on a schedule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-create-rule-schedule.html)
2. [Tutorial: Schedule AWS Lambda functions using EventBridge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-run-lambda-schedule.html)

Comment: This does not run before 9AM on sat and after 9AM on sun.

Comment: True. It was meant as an example. I would expect the OP to read the documentation and build the pattern himself. AFAIK it is about solution design (use EventBridge) and not about the exact pattern etc. But I will try to update.

Comment: The thing is the pattern alone cannot be used to solve this. Excluding the given range needs to be done "manually" within the lambda

Comment: @luk2302 Why? You could also have multiple patterns. Doing this in the Lambda is not ideal from my point of view. Why not have a weekday and a weekend rule. Both pointing to the same Lambda etc.

Comment: I guess I will need to use three different rules for achieving my desired output.@jens

Comment: @Shubham could be. Haven't had time to check again. But the approach is the same. Either you have multiple rules (which I'd personally prefer) or somehow manage this in your Lambda.