# What is the substitute for crond in aws, EventBridge?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge

I am planning to invoke lambda once every hour.

Until now, I was get used to use `crond` to invoke some events on linux.

So, I am googling around what is the substitute for crond in `aws`.

I have heard `EventBridge` works like that.

My understanding is correct?

If so is there any practice for that?

THank you for your advice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I run a AWS Cron Job which will run for the whole week with an exception (I should not run on sat 9 AM to sun 9AM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67785785/how-can-i-run-a-aws-cron-job-which-will-run-for-the-whole-week-with-an-exception)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, AWS Eventbridge is the recommended solution when you want to invoke a lambda (or other) in a scheduled fashion. There's a full tutorial on how to do just that [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-run-lambda-schedule.html).

The Eventbridge rule can [support cron expressions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-create-rule-schedule.html#eb-cron-expressions), too.